# Infusionsoft API Opportunities customFields

Tags: php, api

I have a tab called Buyer's Wish List in opportunity.

I have leads created via API

```
$opportunity = array(
'OpportunityTitle' => $full_name,
'ContactID' => $newCon
);
$app->dsAdd("Lead", $opportunity);
```

Now how do I update custom fields in Buyer's Wish List tab under opportunity via API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old but there has been an update to infusionsoft recently that lets you update the custom field values for opportunities. Use http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/dataservice#update on the lead table:

http://help.infusionsoft.com/developers/tables/lead

The lead table now holds all values for opportunity custom fields.